# How to check a variable for certain strings?

Tags: python

I apologize if I'm not following certain formatting requirements. This is my first time asking a question here and my first programming language. As the topic says, I'd like to check a variable for certain strings. I've tried a few options and have researched it a bit, but have still failed to find a working option.

Just to give you some background, I'm trying to create a word game similar to Zorg (I think that is what it is called). I'm doing this as part of Learn Python the Hard Way [Exercise 35 Extra Practice]. Anyways, here is my code. Thank you very much for your time and help!

```
#First room, allows 3 options    
def firstroom():
    print "You have now begun the test."
    print "For your sake %s, I hope you pass." % name
    print "------------------------------------"
    print "You enter a new room and see three paths."
    print "The middle path is illuminated by an eery blue light."
    print "The left path is illuminated by a dangerous red light."
    print "The right path is illuminated by a soft green glow."
    next = raw_input("What path do you take?" )

    if next in ("left", "red"):
        print "You cautiously approach the left path."
        print "Before you can react, an axe swings down and kills you."
        exit("Thank you %s for playing, unfortunately you died." % name)
    elif next in ("middle", "straight", "blue"):
        print "A smart choice. You slowly head down the middle path."
        print "As you approach the end of the middle path, you see a blue light."
        blueroom()
    elif next in rightpath:
        print "You are lured to the green light."
    else:
        print "Command not recognized."
        firstroom()
```

Comment: I never see `rightpath` defined anywhere

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain what part isn't working to make it easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: Not directly connected to your question but don't use function calls to structure an ”endless” call chain like this.  It will eventually end in an _maximum recursion depth exceeded_ `RuntimeError`. I'd call that an error in the program. Better write an external loop that calls the current room function and let the functions return the function which should be called for the next room to that loop. This way there is always just one active room function instead of an ever growing stack of (mutually) recursive calls.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan That was incredibly silly of me not to include what I was struggling with. So essentially, I want to screen the raw input for certain strings. So far, unless I explicitly type "middle" it won't work and will run through to "else". For example, when I type "The middle path", it goes to the else option. I'd like it to recognize the string "middle" and follow up with that option.

BlackJack Thank you for the advice! I'm new to the lingo so I'll take some time to digest and fully understand what you wrote!

Comment: @AlexLao I understand entirely now and posted an answer. It's quite long so I hope I explained it well. I also agree with BlackJack about possible recursion problems. It's better to loop over the input with a `while True` loop that you break when the user inputs a valid a command.

Answer (score 0):

There is no declaration of the variable `rightpath` in your function. Otherwise, your code looks as if it behaves as you intend it to.

My only suggestion would be to change:

```
elif next in rightpath
```

to

```
elif next == rightpath
```

assuming `rightpath` holds a single `string` value.

**EDIT**

To achieve what you described in your comment, you should split the user input (which could potentially be a sentence) into a list of words:

```
next = raw_input("What path do you take?" ).split()
```

Each comparison will then have to change to incorporate the `any` function:

```
if any(item in next for item in ("left", "red")):
    ...
elif any(item in next for item in ("middle", "straight", "blue")):
    ...
else:
    ...
```

`any` will return `True` any word in the user input exists in your expected list of responses for a given case.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me! Sorry I haven't gotten back sooner, I don't always have wifi.

What I'm having an issue with, besides forgetting to change rightpath to some strings, is when I input things like "The middle path". It doesn't work as I anticipate and it will go to else: If I put in an answer like middle it will work, however I want my code to screen the answer for the characters "middle" I guess?

Comment: Thank you ILoseMySpoon, I didn't think about it this way. The syntax was a little confusing at first, but I think I'm getting the hang of it.

Answer (score -1):

This line isn't quite working the way you think it is:

```
next in ("middle", "straight", "blue")
```

As you said, it works fine if `next = "middle"` but not if it's `the middle path`. That's because this statement will only be `True` if they exactly match, it wont match if part of the string is in the list. ie. You'd need to include:

```
next in ("middle", "straight", "blue", "the middle path")
```

There is a way to do what you want in one line, though it will involve multiple functions.

First, you can check if a specific parameter is in a string with the find method.

```
next.find("middle")
```

will return a number, either the index of where it finds `'middle'` or else `-1` if it cannot find middle anywhere in the string. Using this, you can check if the player entered 'middle' anywhere in the string with this statement:

```
next.find("middle") != -1
```

This returns `True` if middle is in next and false otherwise. But since you want to check multiple parameters, we go a little further. We use something called `any()`, which will basically check a set of conditions and return `True` if any of them are true. We also need to include something called a generator, which is similar to a for loop contained in one line. This is what it will look like:

```
any(next.find(keyword) != -1 for keyword in ("middle", "straight", "blue"))
```

To put it in a clearer way, this is similar to this for loop:

```
for keyword in ("middle", "straight", "blue"):
    if next.find(keyword) != -1:
       found = True
```

It will iterate over your list and if it finds any of the keywords in the `next` string, then it will be `True`. You can use this for each of your `if`s now.

One word of caution, there will be a problem with a string like `"the left blue path"`. Since it has keywords from two if statements, it will just execute whichever it comes across first.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was incredibly helpful!

Comment: Glad to help! Be sure to upvote any answers that were useful and mark whatever answer helped you the most as accepted.

Comment: `str.find() != -1` to check if a substring is present is IMHO too complicated as we have the `in` operator for exactly this scenario. Also you check against 1 and not -1 in your code examples!